# how to add dynamic custom client side validator in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

i have textbox controls that are created dynamically in the ASP.NET. I want to add dynamically custom validators for these controls. These validators should be run on the client side. I have the following code snippet:

```
    protected override void InitDynamicControls()
    {
        registerScript();

        CustomValidator cv = new CustomValidator();
        cv.ErrorMessage = "error";
        cv.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
        cv.ControlToValidate = TextField.ID;
        cv.ValidationGroup = "ConfigurationValidation";
        cv.ClientValidationFunction = "ConfigurationOption_ClientValidate";

        base.Controls.Add(cv);
    }


    private void registerScript()
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder script = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        script.Append("<script language=\"javascript\">\n");
        script.Append("function ConfigurationOption_ClientValidate(source, arguments) \\{arguments.IsValid = false;\\}\n");
        script.Append("</script>\n");

        Type type =  this.GetType();

        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(type, "ConfigurationOption_ClientValidate"))
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type, "ConfigurationOption_ClientValidate", script.ToString());
    }
```

The method in the javascript will contain the logic. Method InitDynamicControls() is loaded in  Page_Load method. When I click the button on the page the validator doesn't run.

can you help me what can be wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
script.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
        script.Append("function ConfigurationOption_ClientValidate(source, arguments) {arguments.IsValid = false; }");
        script.Append("</script>");
```

Or even better use this:

```
private void registerScript()
{
    Type type = this.GetType();

    if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(type, "ConfigurationOption_ClientValidate"))
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type, "ConfigurationOption_ClientValidate", "function ConfigurationOption_ClientValidate(source, arguments) { arguments.IsValid = false; }", true);
}
```